# How to provide a history instance to a saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, redux-saga, react-router-redux

I would like to redirect to a new page after successful login.
The routes (V4) are used like this:

```
import { browserHistory } from '....browser_history_signleton';
...

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { authentication: { isSignedIn } } = this.props;
    return (
      <ConnectedRouter history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
          <Header/>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <PrivateRoute isAuthorized={isSignedIn} path="/page1" component={PageOne}/>
          <PrivateRoute isAuthorized={isSignedIn} path="/page2" component={PageTwo}/>
        </div>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

The saga looks like:

```
import { browserHistory } from '....browser_history_signleton';

export function* loginSaga() {
  while (true) { // eslint-disable-line no-constant-condition
    try {
      const payload = yield take(LOGIN_SUBMIT);
      const raceResult = yield race({
        signin: call(loginRequest, payload),
        logout: take('LOGOUT')
      });
      if (raceResult.signin) {
        const { data }  = raceResult.signin;
        yield put(loginRequestSucceeded(data));
        const redirectUrl = `.....based on location.state.from.pathname`
        browserHistory.push(rediretUrl);
        ...
```

My main issue is how to share `browserHistory`.
`createHistory` from `history` module is not a signleton, so I had to add:

```
// browser_history_signleton.js
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

export const browserHistory = createHistory();
```

What is the most efficient way to provide a `history` instance to a saga?

Comment: The given solution was working as far as I remember: const redirectUrl = 
 = browserHistory.location.state.from.pathname;

Comment: If you have the history object at the time you are creating your store and running your root saga you can pass it as an argument to the root saga. Then you can either pass it again as an arg to the loginSaga (possibly through multiple sagas depending on how deep the loginSaga is) or you can use the setContext/getContext effects to store the history object in the root saga and then retrieve it in your loginSaga,

Comment: Or you can possibly make a new module that will create new instance of history and then export it so you can import the existing instance everywhere you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found two options that felt ok and I've used both. I'm curious to see if anyone has issues with either.

**Option 1: Pass the `history` object around to sagas.**

Its not obvious, but the `sagaMiddleware.run` function takes a second parameter that's forwarded to the sagas. Ie:

```
/wherever/you/start/saga.js

import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import saga1 from "./saga1.js";

const  function* rootSaga({ history }) {
  yield all([saga1({ history })])
}

const sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga, { history: createBrowserHistory() });
```

I learned this here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3972#issuecomment-251189856

This is a clean-ish way of accessing history functionality. In your actual sagas, you'd use the history object like normal.

```
./saga1.js

export default ({ history }) => [
  takeEvery(actions.DO_SOMETHING_THEN_NAVIGATE, function*({ payload }) {
    ...do something
    history.push("/somewhere");
  }),
];
```

**Option 2: Have a single saga manage the `history` object & navigate using actions**

This is an extension of Option 1. Dedicate a saga to "manage" the history object - pushing/replacing using actions. Ie:

```
/my/history/saga.js


export default ({ history }) => [ // history is passed in ala option 1.
  takeEvery(actions.HISTORY_PUSH, function*({ payload }) {
    const pathname = payload.fooParam;
    yield history.push(pathname);
  }),
  takeEvery(actions.HISTORY_REPLACE, function*({ payload }) {
    yield history.replace({ pathname: payload.barParam });
  }),
];
```

This keeps your redux store and actions clean, free of the weird hacks *some* of the community proposes - like passing the history object around in actions.

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, making history directly available as a singleton is one option.  Another similar (if not controversial) approach is to add history to the redux state.  So in your saga, you'd use a select effect to get the history instance.

Both approaches effectively treat history as singletons, but by storing it into the redux state, you can mock the history object a bit easier in unit tests. What I mean by easier is that you can employ the same technique to mock the history object as mocking any other object in the redux state.

Also, you would presumably instantiate the history object along with other initial state so your logic to initialize history wouldn't be a one off exception as to how application state is initialized.