# redux saga and history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, redux-saga

**Backgrond:**
I am creating a `Login` component.

`saga.js` is composed by 3 functions
1. `rootSaga`. It will execute the list of `sagas` inside
2. `watchSubmitBtn`. It will watch the click on the submit button and dispatch an action.
3. `shootApiTokenAuth` will receive dispatched `action` and process `axios.post` the return value is `promise` object

**In action:**
Backend returns `400` to the `React`. This case no problem I can read the `payload` and display in the `render()` easily. But when `200` is returned.
I need to let user go to the url `/companies`.

**Attempt:**
I had tried put `this.props.history.push('/companies');` in the `componentWillUpdate()`, but it does not work. I have to click `Submit` 2 times to get React understand that `token` has been saved.

`Login.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ErrorMessage from "../ErrorMessage";
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {validate} from '../validate';
import {SUBMIT_USERNAME_PASSWORD} from "../../constants";

class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    //Login is stateful component, but finally action will change
    //reducer state
    super(props);
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const isAuthenticated = !((token === undefined) | (token === null));
    this.state = {
      token,
      isAuthenticated,
      message: null,
      statusCode: null
    };
  }

  onSubmit(values) {
    const {userid, password} = values;
    const data = {
      username: userid,
      password
    };
    this.props.onSubmitClick(data);
  }

  componentWillUpdate(){
    console.log('componentWillUpdate');
    if(this.props.isAuthenticated){
      this.props.history.push('/companies');
    }
  }

  renderField(field) {
    const {meta: {touched, error}} = field;
    const className = `'form-group' ${touched && error ? 'has-danger' : ''}`;

    console.log('renderField');

    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <label>{field.label}</label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type={field.type}
          placeholder={field.placeholder}
          {...field.input}
        />
        <div className="text-help">
          {touched ? error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <ErrorMessage
          isAuthenticated={this.props.isAuthenticated}
          message={this.props.message}
        />

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <Field
            name="userid"
            component={this.renderField}
            placeholder="User ID"
            type="text"
          />
          <Field
            name="password"
            component={this.renderField}
            placeholder="Password"
            type="password"
          />
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <a className='btn btn-primary' href="https://www.magicboxasia.com/">Sign up</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const onSubmitClick = ({username, password}) => {
  return {
    type: SUBMIT_USERNAME_PASSWORD,
    payload: {username, password}
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    ...state.login
  }
};

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'LoginForm'
})(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {onSubmitClick})(Login)
);
```

`saga.ja`

```
const shootApiTokenAuth = (values) =>{
  const {username, password} = values;
  return axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/api-token-auth/`,
    {username, password});
};

function* shootAPI(action){
  try{
    const res = yield call(shootApiTokenAuth, action.payload);
    yield put({
      type: REQUEST_SUCCESS,
      payload: res
    });
  }catch(err){
    yield put({
      type: REQUEST_FAILED,
      payload: err
    });
  }
}

function * watchSubmitBtn(){
  yield takeEvery(SUBMIT_USERNAME_PASSWORD, shootAPI);
}

// single entry point to start all Sagas at once
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    watchSubmitBtn()
  ])
}
```

**Problem:**
How can I set the component state and `push` to url `/companies`? after backend returns `200`?

Comment: I had read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893161/how-to-provide-a-history-instance-to-a-saga but not understand

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I usually handle conditional navigation like that in the saga.

The simplest answer with the existing code is to pass a history object as a prop in the SUBMIT_USERNAME_PASSWORD action and do the history.push() call in the success case of the saga, something like:

```
const onSubmitClick = ({username, password}) => {
  const { history } = this.props;

  return {
    type: SUBMIT_USERNAME_PASSWORD,
    payload: {username, password, history}
  };
};
```

.......

```
function* shootAPI(action){
  try{
    const res = yield call(shootApiTokenAuth, action.payload);
    const { history } = action.payload;

    yield put({
      type: REQUEST_SUCCESS,
      payload: res
    });

    history.push('/companies');
  }catch(err){
    yield put({
      type: REQUEST_FAILED,
      payload: err
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I just know that I can pass history! Thank you very much. I always this every properties that prefix by `this` can not be able to passed to the other files. But I was wrong.

Comment: I wish there was a better way to do this. As in, in angular you can directly inject router/history in your saga/effect classes. So there we dont need to pass history around.

Comment: you are genius @brub

Comment: @brub don't you have a feeling that its rather a hack? I mean sending functions and object like history in actions seems like a not expected thing to do. Unfortunately, I can't justify it with my own reasons (though Redux-toolkit has an opinion about that - https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions)

Comment: as I mentioned before in the response to @dasfdsa , i don't pass history thru the functions, it was just s simple example based on the code provided.  normally i initialize my router with a history that i can then import into the sagas.

Answer (score 9):

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';    

yield put(push('/path-to-go'));
```

solved my problem

Comment: This works, but react-router-redux is not maintained anymore and connected-react-router  should be used

Comment: connected-react-router no longer works with react-router v6

Answer (score 1):

I am not as experienced in react but you could achieve it as follows:

1.Create a new Module: **history-wrapper.ts**

```
export class HistoryWrapper {
  static history;
  static init(history){
    HistoryWrapper.history = history;
  }
}
```

2.In you **login.jsx**

```
  HistoryWrapper.init(history);//initialize history in HistoryWrapper
```

3.Subsequently anywhere in your app

```
  HistoryWrapper.history.push('/whatever');
```

Comment: In practice I don't pass the history around as props, I use a similar approach as you are doing using https://github.com/ReactTraining/history.  I initialize my Router using this history object, and then I import it into my sagas and use it directly.

Answer (score -4):

React has additional lifecycle. I just know it today. They are many of them.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.props.history.push('/companies');
  }
```