# Redux-saga, yield call(history.push, 'pathname'), works only the first time, blocking all other call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, generator, redux-saga

I am working with react *16.8.2*.

I have a simple saga watcher code:

```
export default function* taskWatcher() {
  yield all([
    fork(subTaskWatcher1),
    fork(subTaskWatcher2),
  ])
}
```

and a subWatcher code,

```
function* subTaskWatcher2() {
  const actionObj = yield take('ACTION');
  const { history } = actionObj.payload;
  let validated = false;
  //... some Computation to validate navigation ... //
  if (validated) yield call(history.push, '/pathname')
}
```

that intercepts the action and based on some computations, determines whether a new path should be pushed in `history` object or not.

This works well only for the first time I interact with CTA that triggers the code above. All other interactions are missed, as a result of `call` effect of saga being a blocking call.

By this what I mean is, If I navigate back to the page that has the CTA,
and if I click on it again, there is no navigation now.

The discussion on [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3972#issuecomment-316647391) github issue is relevant to my concern.

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47864755/redux-saga-and-history-push) answer. Doesn't really relate to my concern.

I have gone through [redux-saga non-blocking calls](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/NonBlockingCalls.html) page in docs, when I faced similar issue in the past. What is that I am missing to understand sagas and its effects?

Comment: Have you tried using [takeEvery](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeeverypattern-saga-args) or [takeLatest](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takelatestpattern-saga-args) patterns in the taskWatcher() instead of fork?

Comment: I haven't tried it for this case. What is the reason to use `takeEvery` over `fork`?

Answer (score 0):

According to @Jotakun suggestion to use `takeEvery`, after going through [takeEvery pattern](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeeverypattern-saga-args) in saga docs, the following solution seems to work:

```
function* subTask2Worker(actionObj) {
  const { history } = actionObj.payload;
  let validated = false;
  //... some Computation to validate navigation ... //
  if (validated) yield call(history.push, '/pathname')
}

function* subTaskWatcher2() {
  yield takeEvery('ACTION', subTask2Worker);
}

export default function* taskWatcher() {
  yield all([
    fork(subTaskWatcher1),
    fork(subTaskWatcher2),
  ])
}
```